# Python code with Shopify pagination stops midway

Tags: python, pagination, shopify, shopify-api

I have this code where I want to get the Id and the Inventory item Id of all my products.
The problem is that when it arrives at 2000 products aprox it stops iterating the pagination. I don't know if it's a cap of the API or my code isn't ok.

```
import requests
import csv

API_KEY = "key"
PASSWORD = "password"
SHOP_HANDLE = "name"
API_VERSION = '2023-07'  # Actualiza la versión de la API si es necesario
CSV_FILE_PATH = 'product_inventory_item_ids.csv'

def get_all_products():
    page_info = None
    all_products = []

    while True:
        url = f"https://{SHOP_HANDLE}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{API_VERSION}/products.json?limit=250"
        if page_info:
            url += f"&page_info={page_info}"

        response = requests.get(url, auth=(API_KEY, PASSWORD))

        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Error al obtener productos: {response.text}')
            break

        products_data = response.json()

        if not products_data['products']:
            break

        all_products.extend(products_data['products'])
        page_info = products_data.get('next_page_info')

        if not page_info:
            break

    return all_products

def main():
    with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['Product ID', 'Inventory Item ID'])  # Encabezados del archivo CSV
        
        for product in get_all_products():
            product_id = product['id']
            inventory_item_id = product['variants'][0]['inventory_item_id']

            csv_writer.writerow([product_id, inventory_item_id])

    print('Proceso completado. Los datos se han guardado en el archivo CSV.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I managed to use the pagination to get those 2000 products but it stops there and I just don't know why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You know you can solve this much easier with a single Bulk Export query? Your bulk export result would be a list of all your products! As a bonus, each product would also dump the variant info you want, including its item inventory ID. Finally, you get this as a downloadable JSON file from Shopify!

While paging is fun for the whole family and wholesome, bulk exports are far superior for these kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throttle. This is how I do it

```
    def retrieve_all( query_provider, data_retriever):
        has_next_page = True
        edges = []
        cursor = None
        time_to_sleep = -1

        while has_next_page:
            if time_to_sleep > 0:
                time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            query = query_provider(cursor)
            result_ = json.loads(shopify.GraphQL().execute(query))

            throttle = result_["extensions"]["cost"]
            current_points = int(throttle["throttleStatus"]["currentlyAvailable"]) - 200
            last_score = int(throttle["requestedQueryCost"])
            time_to_sleep = (last_score - current_points) / 100

            if 'errors' in result_:
                if result_['errors'][0]['extensions']['code'] == 'THROTTLED':
                    continue
                else:
                    raise Exception(result_['errors'][0]['message'])

            data = data_retriever(result_)
            has_next_page = data['pageInfo']['hasNextPage']
            if len(data['edges']) == 0 and has_next_page:
                raise Exception("You have permission problem going that far")

            edges = edges + data['edges']
            if len(edges) > 0:
                cursor = edges[-1]['cursor']
        return edges
```

And you call this like

```
        def query_provider(cursor):
            after = ""
            if cursor:
                after = ''', after: "%s"''' % cursor
            with open("yourquery.graphql", 'r') as fp:
                return fp.read() % after

retrieve_all(query_provider, lambda s: s['data']['inventoryItems'])
```